# is it possible in C# to know who called a static property/accessor?

Tags: c#, properties, static, accessor

My code:

```
public class CLASS_A {    

public static Dictionary<int, CLASS_A> List = new Dictionary<int, CLASS_A>;
public static PP_CLASS pp = null;

 public static CLASS_A ID
 {
  get
  {
   int key = get_threadID;
   if (List.ContainsKey(key))
     return List[key];
   else
     return null;
   }
   set
   {
    int key = get_threadID;
    List[key] = value;
    }
   }

  public virtual void init(lib, name)
  {
    ...
    if (name != "")
    {
      if (pp == null)
       PP = this;
    } 
    ...
  }
}
```

So whichever thread calls init, it's id is used to store this (whoever called). Eg my list looks like this:

```
45 = CLASS_A_object0
67 = CLASS_A_object1
...
```

But now when a different thread calls a method on pp, say `CLASS_A.pp.setWelcome`, this will return null for pp, and throws null exception! Because when set is called the thread id will be different and won't be in the list.

So is it possible that I know which object called so that I can do reverse lookup? Or maybe a different solution?

**Why I want this:**
Initially we were connecting to one device so that was ok. Now there are multiple devices with each one having its own ip/port. Initial code had just `public static PP_CLASS pp = null;` So others will be just calling methods on pp using class name and things were good.

**Previous behaviour:** The software picks list of devices from a file and since pp is static it only talks to the first device. I added that `pp==null` line which i forgot in my initial post. So when the code starts `pp==null` will be true and first device is assigned, but now for other devices `pp==null` will be false and thus I am not able to talk to other devices.

Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: Can you change the property to a method and add an argument for the "caller"? Then just follow through on all the errors the compiler throws at you.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you want to happen if one thread calls `init` and another thread tries to use `pp`.

Comment: Tell us some more about your use case. Why are you wanting to store your objects with thread as the key? You won't have a separate instance of PP per thread, you'll have a shared PP for all threads after you call PP. This doesn't make much sense as it stands PP and your ID property have no relationship. I'm wondering if you're looking for ThreadStatic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx.
Also - using List as a identifier is not a good thing.

Comment: I thought about that initially, but there are alot of files and is just impractical.

Comment: I'd also suggest using the [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) class, as it can handle the automatic instantiation of a unique instance of an object for each thread that calls it, which is what your code appears to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with [C# 5.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2012/03/26/introduction-of-new-features-in-c-5-0.aspx) (August 2012) there is a new feature "[Caller Info Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx)". If your classes are stored in separate files, you can make use of the `CallerFilePathAttribute` to register which class actually has called.

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx):

```
// using System.Runtime.CompilerServices 
// using System.Diagnostics; 

public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}

// Sample Output: 
//  message: Something happened. 
//  member name: DoProcessing 
//  source file path: c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoCS\CallerInfoCS\Form1.cs 
//  source line number: 31
```

Comment: that one is interesting. (always used the stacktrace in past, this looks simpler)

Answer (score 0):

You could try examining the Stack Trace.

```
var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
```

or to get the calling line only it should be something like:

```
var caller = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(1)
```